# Azure Data Factory user permissions to specific pipeline or linked service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

Using custom roles we can create roles derived from the in-built one and customize the permissions a user can have when the role is assigned to him.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles

With regards to Data Factory, is it a way to create a role with the scope to give permission to a user (r/w/d) only for a specific ADF Pipeline or Linked Service? Or do I need to create 2 Data Factories?

```
  "actions": [
    ...
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories/*",
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/*",
    ...    ]
```

Comment: I believe you would need a separate Data Factory with different permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom role (which is not assignble scope) to give access on a specific pipeline via powershell.

```
“assignableScopes”: [
        “/subscriptions/<<SubscriptionID>>/resourceGroups/<<RGName>>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<<ADFName>>/pipelines/<<PipelineName>>”
    ],
    “permissions”: [
        {
            “actions”: [
                “Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/createrun/action”
            ],
            “notActions”: [],
            “dataActions”: [],
            “notDataActions”: []
        }
    ]
```

For details my blog for reference :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/07/26/security-access-to-trigger-a-specific-pipeline-in-azure-data-factory/